# Can create an instance with `App::make('\App\User')` but not with `new User();`

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

This is the Model:

```
namespace App;

use L5SimpleFM\FileMakerModels\BaseModel;

class User extends BaseModel
{
    protected $connection = 'filemaker';
    protected $layoutName = 'Web : User';
}
```

Which extends this abstract class:

```
namespace L5SimpleFM\FileMakerModels;
use L5SimpleFM\Contracts\FileMakerInterface;  

abstract class BaseModel
    {

        protected $layoutName;
        protected $connection;

        public function __construct(FileMakerInterface $fm)
        {
            $this->connection = $fm->setLayout($this->layoutName);
        }
        ...
    }
```

And this abstract class has an instance(?) of an interface injected.. Now, I don't fully understand dependency injection in this case. When I try to create an instance of my User model using `new User` it fails as it says that it needs a parameter in the `__constructor` as it extends the abstract class BaseModel.

I can create an instance using `App::make('\App\User')` though, and also can create an instance in the controller and get results if I create a route to this method as in the below example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $users)
    {
        $this->user = $users;
    }

    public function findUsers()
    {

        $result = $this->user->findAll()->executeCommand();
        $records = $result->getRows();
        return compact('records');
    }
}
```

and the route:

```
Route::get('user', 'UserController@findUsers');
```

When accessing the above route, I get the desired output but then when I type `new \App\User` in artisan tinker I get:

> TypeError: Too few arguments to function L5SimpleFM\FileMakerModels\BaseModel::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\FMTest\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ExecutionLoop\Loop.php(90) : eval()'d code on line 1 and exactly 1 expected

but `$x = App::make('\App\User');` does work and I can run methods on `$x`.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: _"but not with `new User();`"_ - Where do you have `new User()`? In your `UserController` you pass `Nationality` which you don't have any `use` for.

Comment: I dont. I was trying to do it in tinker and it returns an error, saying that I need to pass a parameter.

Comment: Although in tinker App::make () does work

Comment: Please show us the correct code for the error. The title has currently nothing to do with the code you've posted.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Edited and added error code. Thanks.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `Nationality` was a leftover as I edited the class names before posting here

Comment: Laravels container uses Reflections to check what classes needs to be injected in the constructor and then injects them automatically for you when you use `App::make('\App\User')`. If you create an instance manually, you need to inject the dependencies manually. Since the `BaseModel` requires a class that implements the `FileMakerInterface`, you need to pass an instance of a class that implements that interface. Something like: `new User(new SomeClass)`.

Comment: ^ Controller constructs basically do the same as `app()->make(...)` and automatically resolve dependencies. Using `new Something(..)` you need to pass the instance yourself. That being said I would suggest you avoid overriding default model constructor unless you know exactly what you're doing since you might get some unintentional side effects - especially if you mess with the parameters and are not calling `parent::__construct(...)` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since OP clarified that `BaseClass` is a third party package, this is now the correct answer:

```
namespace App;

use L5SimpleFM\FileMakerModels\BaseModel;

class User extends BaseModel
{
    protected $connection = 'filemaker';
    protected $layoutName = 'Web : User';

    function __construct () {
        parent::__construct(app(FileMakerInterface::class));
    }
}
```

---

Laravel does not offer DI (dependancy injection) in all locations. Often the docs will hint or let you know where you can request dependancies in signatures like in controller methods or constructors. Laravel's model constructors are not eligible for DI requests since instantiating models and assigning data is a method for inserting data via the ORM.

To fix your issue, request `FileMakerInterface` via the global `app()` helper instead of requesting through the constructor.

```
namespace L5SimpleFM\FileMakerModels;
use L5SimpleFM\Contracts\FileMakerInterface;  

abstract class BaseModel
{

    protected $layoutName;
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = app(FileMakerInterface::class)->setLayout($this->layoutName);
    }
    // ...
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#resolving

Comment: FileMakerInterface is an interface, not a class though.

Comment: @Varin if OP registered a provider implementing `FileMakerInterface`, Laravel will inject that provider.

Comment: Ok, it does work this way! Would you mind explain it a bit more? Is this way not a "hacky" way of doing it? (bare in mind that BaseModel is a class from the package I required via composer, not my own file)

Comment: You should not modify files provided by packages installed via composer. If you install your dependencies somewhere else they will get removed. You have two choices: Use *new \App\User(app(FileMakerInterface::class));* when instantiating new Users or override the Base Model Constructor in your \App\User File

Comment: @Varin if the BaseClass is from a vendor, then @shock_gone_wild is correct, do not modify `BaseClass`. Instead I would override your `\App\User` controlled and inject the dependancy.

Comment: @OPatel I can also do this in each model I create: https://pastebin.com/8eA8NCtZ
I contacted the author of the package and he said it should work, and it did when he built it. Did something change in Laravel in the last 2-3 years that made it not work without this modification?

Comment: @Varin I'm not sure about the changes. I've updated my answer to the correct solution, but you seem to have posted that about 4 seconds earlier! Be sure to mark this answer as the correct answer if you think so.